# Android: Exception while playing an mp3 file on a server.

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I am trying to get an audio mp3 file from a server and play it on the android app. 
Here is the code for the function:

```
protected void managerOfSound(String theText) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.reset();
            mp.release();
        }
        URLConnection conn = new URL("http://192.168.1.68:3000/play/song.mp3").openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
        File file = File.createTempFile("downloadingMedia", ".mp3");

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int n = - 1;

        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream( file );
        while ( (n = stream.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
                if (n > 0)
                {
                        output.write(buffer, 0, n);
                }
        }
        output.close();


        System.out.println("PATH IS" + file.getAbsolutePath());
        mp.setDataSource(file.getAbsolutePath());
        mp.start();
    }
```

However, I get a nullpointerexception in the line mp.setDataSource. I verified that the file's absolute path exists.

In the server side too, I verified the requests are being received correctly and its a 200 response.

When I open the URL on the browser, I get the download dialog which asks whether to save or download the file.

Where then is it giving the null pointer exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't gt any response from your url(issue with my proxy)

Have an Eye on this [**Tutorial**](http://blog.infidian.com/2008/04/04/tutorial-custom-media-streaming-for-androids-mediaplayer/)

and [**This**](http://erkutaras.blogspot.in/2011/08/stream-audio-from-url-example-android.html)

Comment: Can you please try it now ?

Comment: Try now ? what do you mean?

Comment: The URL I gave initially pointed to the wrong file. you should be able to connect to it if you don't have any problems.

Comment: yes, the second one worked. 1st one seems a bit complex at this point for me. Thought of up-voting your answer but could not.

Comment: ok glad you solve it you can accept the answer and close this up vote it later